# CakePHP - Router::url doesn't build pretty URLs when there's a regex match in the Router::connect

Tags: regex, cakephp

In my CakePHP, my **routes.php** file looks like this:

```
Router::connect('/premios/:category',
    array('controller' => 'prizes', 'action' => 'category'),
    array(
        'category' => '\bmarcas|restaurantes|combustibles|peluqueria\b',
    ));
```

This way whenever a user enters the /premios url, the next parameter is matched with the "category" regex. This works perfect.

The problem is that when I want to generate a pretty url for the category, let's say, "peluqueria", using this line of code generates **a "non-pretty" url**:

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'prizes', 'action' => 'category', 'peluqueria')); ?>
```

Instead of generating a pretty URL (/premios/peluqueria) it generates a non pretty url (/prizes/category/peluqueria).

**What am I doing wrong?** Or is this a limitation of the `Router::url` function?

A workaround would be to define every connect, avoiding the regex, but it isn't a pretty as the current solution plus it would get annoying when the categories count start to grow.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have `'category' => '\bmarcas|restaurantes|combustibles|peluqueria\b'` in the routes.php file and you are passing `peluquerias` (plural). Is that a typo for purposes of this example or is it the actual problem? (if it's just a typo, please fix it in the question)

Comment: Typo, sorry. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually name the `category` parameter in `Router::url`, like this

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'prizes',
                  'action'     => 'category', 
                  'category'   => 'peluqueria'));
```

And you'd probably want to pass that "category" parameter to the category action in Prizes, so you're missing something

```
Router::connect(
    '/premios/:category',
    array('controller' => 'prizes', 'action' => 'category'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('category'),
        'category' => '\bmarcas|restaurantes|combustibles|peluqueria\b'
    )
);
```

Look [this part](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) of the docs with more detention :)

Comment: I LOVE YOU. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: FYI, i wasn't passing the parameters because i was finding them in $this->request->params->pass[0]

Comment: True, but doesn't `public function category($category = null)` looks prettier :) Matter of preference.